# Best way (program/statistical DSL/library) to curve fit data containing multiple y-values for some x-values

Tags: curve-fitting

My data is as follows:

```
X1   Y2         Y3         Y4         Y5     Y6
0    1          1          1          1      1  
1    1.33333    -          1.22222    -      1.2
2    -          1.90909    2          -      1.8
3    -          -          2.6        -      2.2
4    2          -          3.51111    2.1    3.2
5    -          -          4          -      4.6
6    2.33333    3.09091    5.28889    2.9    5.6
7    2.53333    2.81818    5.37778    3      5.8
8    2.23333    3.27273    -          3.2    6.4
9    2.56666    4          -          4.1    8.4
```

[image: Plot of each Y series against X]

I currently have the above data. As you can see I have multiple Y values for some X values. This is because each Y column represents data from a different source. What I want is for a program (like SciDavis, which I am currently using) to curve fit a function to *all* of this data, not just one X-Y column combination like SciDavis is doing when I (in other words I want to see a nice curve in between the light blue and the red/dark blue graphs, an average curve so the speak).

I have tried numerous search terms to find a way to do this in SciDavis, and to find other programs to do this, but to no avail. I am hoping that someone experienced in this can give me a good suggestion for a program that can do this (or a domain specific programming language/statistical package combined with a library if need be. I can program as well, in fact I am trying to find a function that I can use as a part of a model that I will be using in a simulation that I am coding)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use any regression analysis program.

Organize your data into two columns, one for x and one for y. You probably also want to include a third column that denotes the column of y that each value came from.

For each value of x you will have several rows, one for each observed y.

Estimate a model using a polynomial, probably in x and x^2.

If you want a regression for specific subsets of the original y columns then restrict your analysis to those cases.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Are there any (free and cross-platform, please) programs that you recommend for a non-expert for this? Or do you recommend investing a little bit of time to learn working with something like GNU Octave or R and an appropriate library?

Comment: @Superpelican If you use R you don't need a library for that, you can do it right from the vanilla R package (using poly within `lm` to fit). I'm not sure I'd necessarily advise a polynomial fit though (I'd probably use local linear regression or splines if I had a good reason to do this at all) and the difference in spread with size might suggest working on a different scale. You'll also have an issue in that the pattern of missingness will introduce unnecessary wiggles to the fit (since the Y's are at different levels).

Comment: I'm reluctant to recommend a specific statistical package. I usually think that a better one to use is one that other people around you are using. That way you can often get an informal consult when needed. Ask around.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to explain more about what you're doing and what you're hoping to achieve.

Taking it at face value, as mentioned in comments, I'd try a different scale -- specifically, since all the data start from exactly 1 and "spread out" from there -- I'd subtract 1 and take logs from the y-values, and if smoothness is expected, then I'd fit a smooth curve against log(x) (with natural splines at low df, say), and use the y-column indicator in the model. Then estimating the overall fit at the average level, and transforming everything back (exponentiate and add 1). The result would be like a geometric-mean curve (of the data-1).

[image: Spline fit to the "middle" of the groups]

If you wanted something nearer the arithmetic mean you'd add an upshift of $s^2/2$ before the exponentiation (where the level shift is), which would just tilt it up a little -- but I wouldn't do that in this case; the higher curves are "noisier" on the raw scale and I think the geometric mean is the better choice.

[If you don't seek a smooth curve you just fit a factor in levels of X as well as the column indicator.]

Here's how I did that:

```
pel=read.table(stdin(),head=TRUE)
    X1   Y2         Y3         Y4         Y5     Y6
    0    1          1          1          1      1  
    1    1.33333    NA         1.22222    NA     1.2
    2    NA         1.90909    2          NA     1.8
    3    NA         NA         2.6        NA     2.2
    4    2          NA         3.51111    2.1    3.2
    5    NA         NA         4          NA     4.6
    6    2.33333    3.09091    5.28889    2.9    5.6
    7    2.53333    2.81818    5.37778    3      5.8
    8    2.23333    3.27273    NA         3.2    6.4
    9    2.56666    4          NA         4.1    8.4

pels=(data.frame(X=rep(0:9,5),stack(pel[,-1])) ) 
tpels=data.frame(lvm1=log(pels$values-1),lX=log(pels$X),ind=pels$ind)[pels$values>1,]

library(splines)
lfit4=lm(lvm1~ns(lX,4)+ind,tpels)
mlev4=sum(lfit4$coefficients[6:9])/5
newp=data.frame(lX=log(seq(.1,9,.1)),ind=rep(tpels$ind[1],90))
ppred=predict(lfit4,newdata=newp)
plot(values~X,pels,col=ind,pch=16)
lines((exp(ppred+mlev4)+1)~exp(newp$lX),col="dimgrey",lwd=2)
```

Comment: I am writing a game for which I need to roughly calculate the growth of air travel (demand) for each continent/region from the 1970s through 2015 (and also the projected growth for the next 20 years). I was hoping that I could use something like SciDavis to quickly get a nice function, but it has become obvious to me that this is not possible. I have decided to just go with a simple linear model, which I have found by just playing around with the steepness of the slope in SciDavis. I think this approach is accurate enough for my purposes.

Comment: The thing is that players' actions will be influencing the game a lot as well, therefore perfectly representing the growth of air travel is probably going to be rather pointless. Honestly, I don't want to spend too much time on this part of the game because of this. I really appreciate your reply, and I am sure that it will benefit someone else reading it in the future a lot, but I think that I am better off taking another path to avoid overkill.